# Scalactic: convert an Iterable to Every

Tags: scala, scalactic

Using scalactic, one can convert an `Every` to a `List` like this:

```
scala> Every(1,2,3).toList
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

How can I perform the reverse operation, though, i.e. try to convert a `List` or an `Iterable` to an `Every`? Is there a built-in method that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
val everyOpt: Option[Every[Int]] = Every.from(List(1, 2, 3))
```

If the list is known to be non empty:

```
val every: Every[Int] = Every.from(List(1, 2, 3)).get
```

Comment: Doh! I'll remember to look up the documentation for the companion object next time. For reference: http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.6/#org.scalactic.Every$